# Text wont wrap around image in Chrome

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, css-float

I have an image in the top left corner of the main content div of my page. For some reason I cannot seem to get text to properly float around the image. Instead, it is sending it down to the next line underneath the image, treating it like a block element. In all other browsers it works, the problem is with Chrome only. The code is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: How about showing us your code or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the code would be useful. Here are some quick stabs at solving the problem:

1) Is the image displayed block-level (`display: block;`)?
2) Is there an element with a clear attribute?

I would also try using Firebug to analyze the problem: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Thank you, I just got Firebug, now I just have to learn how to use it. Question...Does Firefox and Chrome mostly present html/css the same way?

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox are pretty W3C standards-compliant, so they do. Nonetheless, Firefox is based off of Gecko browser engine, and Chrome is based off of Webkit. All in all, there are some differences, but both adhere to standards well.

Comment: Is IE not very standards compliant? Is that why all my stuff looks like garbage on that browser? Thanks so much for your help. I am new to this as you can tell

Comment: Haha yeah, IE is the sadly the bane of many web developers :(